# Using Celery when each function is dependent of each others List output

Tags: python-3.x, list, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I have three functions here that returns list, which also makes them dependent to each other.

```
keyword_list = search_keyword.delay()

images_list = collect_images.delay(keyword_list.get())

if images_list.successful():
   save_images.delay(images_list .get())
```

I think in this case I am using Celery inefficiently. Because it just runs it sequentially. I read about chains but I dont think it can be applied to this case. Or can it be applied to it? I have searched for the same scenario I am having but I cant.

The reason why I get lists for these functions is because they are using third party integrations/services

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [Chain](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#chains) seems suitable for this use-case. In the chain, output of the previous task in the chain is input to the next task in the chain. However you may need to refactor the save_images because you can't have that "if" statement there. The simplest thing is that collect_images() returns an empty list, or None, and save_images() does nothing if it gets an empty list or None.